# Extra <li>s are generated in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm setting up a new website/landing page. If you go to the right column at the bottom (pictures) you will see `<li>`s with pictures in containers. Everything works great except in IE8 and IE9, extra blank picture containers are generated between the 2nd and 3rd pictures and between the 3rd and 4th pictures. It's as if there should be a thumbnail there but there's nothing in the container.

http://mattmillermusic.com.previewdns.com

Perhaps it's just a case of code blindess since I've been at my computer non stop for a while but I find it odd that these empty LI's don't show up in the other browsers (or in IE7).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of an error in your markup. You do not have closing tags for some of the elements.

[image]

In the picture, as you can see (in red). The browser compensates by auto-inserting them, in the process creating redundant elements.

As you can see, you do not have closing tags for `<a>` elements form your second `<li>` onwards.

Comment: Ah thank you! I knew it was something boneheaded haha. Definitely was staring at all of that for too long yesterday. Thanks!